# Sharing a window in Teams with a custom WindowChrome flashes the original window chrome

Tags: wpf, microsoft-teams, windows-11

I have a WPF desktop application with a window with a custom chrome. As soon as I set the WindowChrome style-property of the window, I have an issue when sharing that window in teams: the window chrome is toggling between the classic one, and my custom chrome.

There is no issue when sharing the screen instead of the window.
We have this problem with Windows 11, but not Windows 10.
Below the full XAML to reproduce this:

```
   <Window x:Class="ControlTester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlTester"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This is my window with WindowChrome set"/>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

When sharing the window in Teams (Share content->Window)...

[image]

... both the presenter and the others in the meeting/call see this:
[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by : "when sharing that window in Teams" ?
there are many ways to share in Teams ...

Comment: The issue occurs when sharing the actual window. No problem when sharing the screen.

Comment: ok, so you mean : During a teams call or meeting,  share your web app running in  <which browser> something happens.
Do you have a minimal repo ?

Comment: It is not a web app. It's a WPF desktop app.

Comment: Minimal repro: Create a new WPF dekstop application. Set the style I posted in my question. Share the application in a Teams meeting or call on Windows 11.

Comment: @Coder14 -  Could you please share the repro steps on how are you sharing your app in Teams meeting or call? Are you talking about Teams window sharing during call/meeting?

Comment: Also could you please share the screenshots for your issue.

Comment: Added screenshots of the issue and how we use the share window functionality in Teams. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Coder14 - Could you please try updating your Teams desktop client and check it once. Also could you please check it with Teams web client (Https://teams.microsoft.com) whether it's working on web or not.

Comment: I have the latest version (according to Teams): 1.4.00.29469 (64-bit).
The problem does not occur with the Teams web client.

Comment: @Coder14 - Are you facing any issue related to Teams app development?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I'm not developing a Teams app. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please raise a issue in Teams Desktop client like below:

1. Open Teams desktop client and go to left side panel and click on Help.
2. Select "Report a problem" and select appropriate category for your issue and raise a request.

[image]

Comment: There is no "Report a problem", only "Give feedback". In the popup it opens there is no way to add screenshots, so I just linked to this post.

Comment: There's also no way to follow up the issue.

Comment: For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to Microsoft 365 Product Support here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business-video/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online

For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on Microsoft Teams Community here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1